# Regex Including Characters in a Non-Capturing Group?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a song titles like:

> ```
> Cant Stop (feat. Akon)
> American Superstar feat Akon
> American Superstar ft someone
> American Superstar ft. someone
> ```

I am trying to match just the title, Can't Stop. I came up with this regex using a mixture of regexr and expresso:

```
(.*)(?:\(?ft|feat)
```

It matches them all Ok except for Can't Stop where is seems to be including the parenthesis in the match. I am obviously doing something wrong but i have been playing with it for 4 hours and i cant figure out what it is, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it with this.

```
(.+?)(?:\(|ft|feat)
```

Comment: neat, a good tool i use to check regex on the fly is rubular, http://rubular.com/r/iuxKDBv5qZ

Comment: @OliverAtkinson thats awesome another tool to add to my collection, i normally use Regexr (http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), but it never hurts to have a backup though :)

Answer (score 2):

`(?:\(?ft|feat)` doesn't match "(feat", because the `\(?` is only part of the left side of the `|`.  It will match "(ft" or "feat", but not "(feat".   Since you want the possibility of a "(" whether or not "feat" is abbreviated, you should move the `\(?` outside of the `(?:...)`.

After you fix that, then you still have the greediness problem that @動靜能量 mentioned, which you can fix by appending `?` to the `.*` so that it only matches the minimum number of characters needed.

That gives this, which works on all your examples:  `(.*?)\(?(?:ft|feat)`

Answer (score 0):

The `.*` is what is called "greedy" and it will match the opening paren.  (Since you specified later that an opening paren is optional, this optional part is not matched). To exclude it, `[^(]*` can be used instead.

Comment: That would work if the greediness were the only problem, but it's actually precedence as well; see my answer.

Comment: @MarkReed greediness is also a problem

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
(.*?)(?=\(?(ft|feat))
```

It sums up what was said in the other answers (the greediness and the precedence problem) plus it uses a positive lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

Taylor now your answer will match inputs with just open bracket or for that matter even without feat or ft.
 I would advise you to skip using bracket or else use like the following (.+?)(?:\(?(ft|feat))